# IPA file is not generating in Azure Devops Pipeline Integration for ReactNative iOS Application

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, react-native-ios, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to set up CI/CD using the Azure pipeline for my React Native iOS application. Unfortunately, I don't see .ipa being generated in the 'XCode' task. I do see that the archive was created successfully and I do have the checkbox to generate the package. Below is my current yml file.

```
 - task: Xcode@5
   inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'Release'
    sdk: 'iphonesimulator'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'SampleProject.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'SampleProject'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    provisioningProfileName: 'Enterprise.mobileprovision'

 - task: CopyFiles@2
   inputs:
   Contents: '**/*.ipa'
   TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
   OverWrite: true

 - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
   inputs:
   PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
   ArtifactName: 'ios'
   publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?